# "A week having passed without hearing back from her"

Tags: sentence-construction

I am writing a sentence:

> A week passed without hearing back from her, Michael started calling her friends.

This, of course, is a run-on sentence. To fix it, I tried this:

> A week on (later) without hearing back from her, Michael started calling her friends.

This sounds better. But I wonder how I can make the sentence work while retaining the verb "pass". To make it a non-finite verb, I tried:

> A week having passed without hearing back from her, Michael started calling her friends.

This sounds really stilted to me, but I guess it is grammatical. Are there better ways to make it work without having to add a conjunction?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you saying that you want to use the verb "pass" *and also* keep it as a non-finite (like a gerund or a participle), i.e. "having passed" or "passing" or "to pass" or something like that?  Otherwise there are a number of ways to structure this sentence, for example just start with **"After ..."**.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: Okie dokie.  Then I think HiddenBabel's edited answer is pretty much the limit of the available options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the word **so**:

> A week passed without hearing back from her, **so** Michael started calling her friends.

Edit: I don't think you can keep it a dependent clause as you wanted. However, I think if you switched the order of your last sentence,

> Having passed a week without hearing from her, ...

that doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I am looking for...

Comment: @EddieKal  Perhaps we don't quite understand what you want to say then, since "so" seems perfectly correct to me.  In this context it means something like "therefore", without being as stilted.

Comment: What are you going for, more specifically?

Comment: @Andrew I understand it appears a simple conjunction works wonders here. It does. But I am trying to make the first clause a non-finite dependent clause, for stylistic reasons.

Comment: @EddieKal  I see.  That makes sense.  However if you want to keep the first clause independent, it rules out many more options than just the conjunction, I think.

Comment: This works. +1. I will wait a bit and see if there's other ideas coming along.